# What is the difference between two forms of matrix coherence?

Tags: matrix, svd

I am stuck on the definition of coherence of a matrix. Let $x_1, \dots, x_p \in \mathbb{R}^p$ be the columns of the matrix $X$, which are assumed to be normalized such that $x'_i x_i = 1$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_coherence_(linear_algebra)#cite_note-tropp-1) defines the coherence of $A$ as $\max_{1 \leq i \neq j \leq p} |x'_ix_j|$. This quantity measures the strength of correlation (more precisely, inner product) among columns of $A$.

Let the SVD of $A$ be $UDV'$. [Talwalkar and Rostamizadeh](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1408/1408.2044.pdf) defined the coherence of a matrix of $V$ as
$$
\mu(V) = \sqrt{n}\max_{i,j} |V_{(i)}^{(j)}|
$$
where $V_{(i)}^{(j)}$ is the $(i,j)$ entry of $V$. Intuitively, $\mu(V)$ measures the extent to which the principal direction vectors depend on each variable.

I have read the post [Confusing definitions of matrix coherence in linear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502154/confusing-definitions-of-matrix-coherence-in-linear-algebra), but I still can not understand the nature and relation between the two definitions. For example, I write the following R codes,

```r
a = matrix(1:16,byrow = TRUE, ncol = 4)
n = ncol(a)
nm_a = apply(a,2,function(x){norm(as.matrix(x),type = "F")})
for (i in 1:ncol(a)) {
  a[,i] = a[, i]/nm_a[i]
}

ata = t(a) %*% a

for (i in 1:ncol(ata)) {
  ata[i,i] = 0
}

svd_a = svd(a)

sqrt(n) * max(abs(svd_a$v)) # 1.632434
max(abs(ata)) # 0.9991746
```

Thus, my question is, what is the relation between $\max_{1 \leq i \neq j \leq p} |x'_ix_j|$ and $\sqrt{n}\max_{i,j} |V_{(i)}^{(j)}|$.

Comment: It is important to recognize that the meaning of "correlation" in this context is *not* the usual statistical one.  Your references use "correlation" as a synonym for the (dot) product of two unit vectors--not necessarily centered at zero.  You are wise to be wary of that post on the Math site you reference: its one answer is incorrect and nonsensical (*e.g.,* it refers to a number as if it were a vector).

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your helpful comment! I saw this moment the comment you left it. I know what you mean, and I have edited the post.

Comment: The `R` code is not a good illustration, due to the special nature of `a`.  Regardless, a key point overlooked here is that Talwalkar and Rostamizadeh's definition of coherence is explicitly for *orthonormal* matrices, not general matrices.